# Error with 'Clipboard.SetText(Variable)'

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

When I try to use the command 'Clipboard.SetText(Variable), I get error:

> error BC30451: 'clipboard' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

What might be wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText()` instead of `Clipboard.SetText()`

Comment: Um, could you explain WHY this 'error' happened or why I have to do My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText() instead?

Comment: @Meraj99: No - I can't reproduce your error. `Clipboard.SetText("...")` works fine for me...

Answer (score 1):

you variable must be a `string` object otherwise use `Clipboard.SetData()` or `Clipboard.SetDataObject()`